# How to escape apostrophe in WSO2 property XPath expression

Tags: xpath, escaping, xpath-2.0, wso2-esb

My problem is to quote the values obtained from **get-property('cf')** in    
`<property expression="fn:concat(get-property('whereConcat'),' AND PA_INATO=', get-property('cf'))" name="whereConcat" scope="default" type="STRING"/>`

I have tried in different ways(character encoding:`&apos;`, character escape: `\'`) but without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the cleanest way is to define a constant:

```
<property name="apos" scope="default" type="STRING" value="'"/>
```

and then use it as follow:

```
<property expression="fn:concat(get-property('whereConcat'),' AND PA_INATO=',get-property('apos'), get-property('cf'),get-property('apos'))" name="whereConcat" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```