# How to use apostrophe character in the fn:concat-property expression WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm having a problem with using apostrophe character in the  property expression. 
I tried ', \', but they were failed. So, currently I'm managing myself with defining it as another property as mentioned below.

```
<property value="'" name="apos" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property description="xpathexpr" expression="fn:concat('$ctx:hotel-static-data-rs//jsonObject/rows[id=',$ctx:apos,'hotelbeds_v3-',$ctx:hotelcode,$ctx:apos,']/value')" name="xpathexpr" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<property description="hotel-static-data-element" expression="evaluate($ctx:xpathexpr)" name="hotel-static-data-element" scope="default" type="OM"/>
```

I'm sure there must be a better way to handle this. So, if anyone have a clue please update.

- WSO2 ESB version : 5.0.0

Comment: You can try[1]. 

[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862240/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-wso2-property-xpath-expression

Comment: I'm also currently doing it in the same way, vivekanathan. I have mentioned in the question. I thought there must be a better way than defined it as a constant.

Answer (score 4):

Try replace apostrophe character as this example.

```
<property name="hotelContentExpr"
                   expression="fn:concat('//content[hotelcode=','&#34;',get-property('htlCode'),'&#34;',']')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Ernesto. But this &#34 is for Quotation right? Not for apostophe. Apostophe is &#39. (References : https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html, http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php, http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/HTMLchrc.html.) 

But &#39 is also not allowed. Anyway when I add quotation also my expression works. Still interseted on handling apostophe. :)