# Stroe Values in a Cache - WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I have data as I mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042884/filter-data-from-json-by-checking-condition-with-two-properties-wso2-esb) (later may be I will have large data). The data I got by calling an end point in an API. I need to call the endpoint and parse the data annd store in a cache only once (only first time) and later I should not call the end point. When next time I call the API, the parsed data should be retrieved from cache.

Is this option available in WSO2-ESB?

Please advise me. Thanks in advance.